# Exception when trying to use spring data mongo repository with Stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have MongoRepository extended and want to use the Stream API. As by the reference, I declared a query method:

```
public Stream<MyType> findByIdIn(Iterable<? extends String> myTypeIds);
```

However, when starting up my Spring Boot application, a `PropertyNotFoundException`is thrown stating:

> No property id found for type Stream!

My domain type derives from a supertype containing the actual id of the MongoDB object. Any ideas how to fix this?

I am using Spring Boot 1.2.0.RELEASE and Spring Data MongoDB 1.6.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for `Stream` as a return-type was added in Spring Data MongoDB version 1.7, [as per the release notes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.1-7-0):

> #### What’s new in Spring Data MongoDB 1.7
>
> ...
>
> - Allow `Stream` as query method return type

Therefore, you need to update from 1.6.1.RELEASE to at least version 1.7. If you are using Maven, you could add the following dependency for the current latest version, which is 1.8.2.RELEASE:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. It in fact sufficed to point the <parent> of my spring boot project to spring boot 1.3.0.RELEASE, which includes the 1.8.1.RELEASE for Spring data Mongo. All issues fixed!