# How to use Stream with Mongo db in spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, java-stream, mongorepository

I want to query large collection in Mongodb and tryin to use Stream `com.mongodb.connection.Stream` . I am doing this in spring boot using `MongoRepository`. I get error `Type 'com.mongodb.connection.Stream' does not have type parameters` for the method `Stream<Population> findAllStates(String state);`. Not sure what is the Type its complaining.

I have collection `Population` in the mongodb.

My Repository class is

```
package com.krk.samplemongodb;

import com.mongodb.connection.Stream;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface PopulationRepository extends MongoRepository<Population, String> {


    @Query(value = "{'state' :?0}")
    Stream<Population> findAllStates(String state);

    List<Population> findAll();
    
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should change your import to

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
```

Also, make sure to use at least version 1.7 of Spring Data MongoDB as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35324016/5050667)

Comment: Awesome. That worked. Is there example how this stream can be used? Does this needs to be closed after iterating through all objects?

Comment: @neoczar it's a typical Java stream, so it can only be consumed once but no need to close it. To get another stream, you need to call the method again

Comment: @neoczar You don't iterate the stream, it is mostly used for data transformation (not storage, like a collection).See this article on Java Streams: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html

Comment: @neoczar If you want to aggregate data (a common usage of Java streams), in this application, you should be using MongoDB Aggregations. This would be efficient, rather than using streams.

Answer (score 0):

Up to @neoczar. Maybe too late but according to the documentation of Spring Data Mongodb the stream should be closed to release the server-side resources (cursor). So you can use try with resources to automatically close cursor.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.aggregation